# C# Pulling the Count of tables Associated with ID

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc

Hello I have two tables that look like the following:

PeriodValue

- Id (PK)
- Name
- Description
- StartDate
- EndDate
- ActiveFlg

AcademicTerm

- Id (PK)
- Year Id (FK)
- Name
- Start Date
- End Date

The objective is to pull the count of terms associated with every period value. This is my code to do so.

```
public async Task<PeriodValueDTO> GetSchoolYearPeriodValueDTOById (int periodValueId)
{
    var value = await Db.PeriodValues.FindAsync(periodValueId);

    return new PeriodValueDTO()
    {
        id = periodValueId,
        Name = value.Name,
        StartDate = value.Date.ToShortDateString(),
        EndDate = value.EndDate.ToShortDateString(),
        Description = value.Description
    };
}
```

This method calls the one above

```
public async Task<List<PeriodValueDTO>> GettAllPeriodValueDTOsByType(int periodTypeId)
{
    var toReturn = new List<PeriodValueDTO>();
    var pvs = await Db.PeriodValues.Where(x => x.PeriodTypeId == periodTypeId).ToListAsync();
    var pvIds = pvs.Select(x => x.Id).ToList();
    var periodPeriodVal = await Db.Period_PeriodValue.Where(x => pvIds.Contains(x.PeriodValueId)).ToListAsync();

    foreach (var ppv in periodPeriodVal)
    {
        var periodValue = pvs.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == ppv.PeriodValueId);
        var value = await GetSchoolYearPeriodValueDTOById(periodTypeId);
        var rightId = value.id; //Added this
        var terms = Db.AcademicTerms.Where(x => x.YearId == rightId).ToArray();  //Changed This
        var dto = new PeriodValueDTO()
        {
            id = periodValue.Id,
            Name = periodValue.Name,
            StartDate = periodValue.Date.ToShortDateString(),
            EndDate = periodValue.EndDate.ToShortDateString(),
            Description = periodValue.Description,
            Count = terms.Length //Changed this
        };
        toReturn.Add(dto);
    };
    return toReturn;
}
```

However I am getting this error:

- Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
- Error: Resolving failed with a reason `[object Object]`, but no `resolveFailed` provided for segment `SchoolYear`

If I comment out the lines that include var terms, var value, and Count it runs. When they are included I get the error above.

Still a novice to this. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely because of this line:

```
var terms = Db.AcademicTerms.Where(x => x.YearId == value.id);
```

Here, you are trying to generate an expression to be translated into SQL and executed on the database (because `Db.AcademicTerms` is `IQueryable`). You are not executing this query in memory. The query parser tries to convert `value` to a SQL parameter and fails because it is not a primitive object. So you have two choices:

1. Save `value.id` into a separate variable and then use that in your query, or better:
2. Save all `AcademicTerms` into memory before your loop (I assume there are not hundreds of them) by calling `.ToArray()` and then query against this. This also resolves the additional [N+1 Selects antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-selects-issue) you have, while allowing greater flexibility.

Comment: I really appreciate your insight. Implemented your changes above. Running it now, if it works will give you green check

Answer (score 1):

```
var value = await GetSchoolYearPeriodValueDTOById(periodTypeId);
```

should be :

```
var value = await GetSchoolYearPeriodValueDTOById(periodValue.Id);
```

no ?